# I want to use an array of elements as the keys of a hash but some of the keys are missing

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key

```
    my %seen;
    @seen{@sender} = ();
    my @merged = (@sender, grep{!exists $seen{$_}} @receiver);


    my $c1 = @merged;
    print $c1, "\n";


    @hash{@merged} = ();
    my @email = keys %hash;

    my $c2 = @email;

    print $c2, "\n";
```

This is the part of code that I wrote for the purpose in the title.

c1 prints 1409 while c2 prints only 493.
I want to know where went wrong that almost 1000 elements are missing (not in the key for the hash)?

Alternatively, if I do this:

```
    foreach (@merged) {
        $hash{$_} = ();
    }
    # @hash{@merged} = ();
    my @email = keys %hash;
```

to assign keys, it still only gives me 493 keys, missing almost 1000 others.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have repeats in `@sender` or `@receiver`. (Repeats in `@sender` will increase `c1`; repeats in `@receiver` will increase `c2`.)

Comment: Yes I do. But what I want to achieve is: First, merger "sender" (1000 values) and "receiver" (1000 values) and eliminate duplicates, which creates "merged" that has 1409 values (smaller than 2000). Second, use these 1409 values as keys for "hash".

Comment: But "eliminates duplicates" does not work properly. For example, if `@sender` has `("a", "a", "a")` and `@receiver` has `("a", "a")`, you would expect the merge to either have `("a")` (dedup) or `("a", "a", "a", "a", "a")` (no dedup); yours has `("a", "a", "a")`, which gives you the discrepancy. When you use them as hash keys, this performs a proper dedup, and only `("a")` remains, for difference of 2 between `c1` and `c2`.

Comment: But the merged array has 1409 elements which feels right (reasonably smaller than 2000). And why would this affect assigning keys to the hash? Why the hash only has 493 keys? It should has 1409 keys.

Comment: I just demonstrated a possible scenario. I won't tell for sure unless I see the data. You will not get anything from `@receiver` if `@sender` already has it, so you have 597 elements in `@receiver` that are also in `@sender`. But you still have 916 dupes (multiple values in `@sender`, or multiple values in `@receiver`) - those will get collapsed when you index a hash.

Comment: Oh I now understand. Thanks! Actually as long as I get all the unique keys it should be fine.

Comment: 3 questions asked today and no accepted answers. You should accept the answer which works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my %seen;
@seen{@sender} = ();
my @merged = (@sender, grep{!exists $seen{$_}} @receiver);
```

mixes two ways of finding unique values, without doing either right. To get the unique values, change the above to

```
my %seen;
@seen{@sender} = ();
@seen{@receiver} = ();
my @merged = keys(%seen);
```

or

```
my %seen;
my @merged = grep !$seen{$_}++, @sender, @receiver;
```

The latter preserves order.